# What will happen if I serialized one class object and later modified one field and moved that field to Parent class?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have one class Object and persisted it. Now I want to make super class of that existing class and moved one field to parent class.

When I am de-serializing the object it's giving that field value as null.

```
Class A{
int a;
String b;
}
```

I persisted this class object.

I create new class.

```
Class B{
String b;
}
```

I extend B class to A.

```
class A extends B{
int a;
}
```

Now when I want to de-serialize the existing stored object, it is giving b field value as null;

Comment: The reason is clear that _serialVersionUID_ of the previous class and new class are different. Actually if the class doesn’t define _serialVersionUID_, it’s getting calculated automatically and assigned to the class. Java uses class variables, methods, class name, package etc to generate this unique long number.

Comment: I have provided the serialVersonUID for both Base and Derived class same as private static final long serialVersionUID = 1000L;

Comment: @Mihir If that was the problem there would have been an exception.

Answer (score 2):

All sorts of bad things can happen if you make a significant change to a class when there are serialized instances of the old version.

In this case, you have made an incompatible change at the representation level, but (in effect) told the serialization system that the old and new representations are compatible ... because you are using the same serialVersionUID value in the old and new versions of the class.

I'm also guessing that while class `A` (the subclass) implements `Serializable`, class `B` (the superclass) does not.  When a serializable class has a non-serializable superclass, the fields of the superclass don't get serialized.  When the class is de-serialized, the non-serializable superclasses no-args constructor is invoked.  In your example, the `B` constructor must be initializing (or default initializing) the field `b` to `null`.

Getting versioning right with serialization is tricky.  If you are contemplating making changes to serializable classes AND you want to be able to use previously serialized objects, then you should read [Chapter 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) of the Object Serialization Specification carefully.  In fact, you should probably read the entire spec.

In general Java Object Serialization is not a good choice if there is any possibility that you will need to evolve the serializable classes.  Text-based serialization schemes (like JSON or XML) are more robust and more "forgiving".  Alternatively, a database may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Java's serialization API unfortunately is not designed for *this kind of* change to the code. I would recommend serializing to JSON or something if you're going to be making changes like this. It's more work, but I would say it's worth it for future-proofing.

Comment: It is designed for exactly that. You need to read, and explain the existence of, [Versioning of Serializable Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) in the Object Serialization Specification. Answer is completely incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified *this kind of change.* I have read that document in the past, and I re-read it just now, and your answer highlights why it's not made for this kind of change: a member being moved from a subclass to a superclass *while maintaining the same member name* is retrieved as `null`, not the original value. This seems wrong to me, and writing your own serialization code -- while more work -- I consider worth the extra work. I understand why `Serializable` is the way it is, but it has many disadvantages to a project-specific solution, and this is one of them.

Comment: You are still mistaken. It is designed specifically for this kind of change: an addition and a deletion. What it isn't designed for is an arbitrary shifting  of fields between base and derived classes. I have my doubts as to whether anything else is so designed. If you have evidence to the contrary please produce it.

Comment: `Object o = getSerializedClass().getConstructor().newInstance(); for (Entry<String,Object> e : getSerializedFields()) { getSerializedClass().getField(e.getKey()).set(o, e.getValue()); }` with some error checking would handle it just fine. But I personally would use `Externalizable` and a JSON library, so that if I needed to make weird changes, I could handle it semantically. Like I said, it's a little more work, but it allows you to handle things like this in a better way than just returning `null`, which is what `Serializable` does.

Comment: IOW with 'a little more work' you can handle this case just fine with 'Serializable'. So what exactly is your point about JSON? And your proposed implementation?

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I've just worked on enough cross-platform systems that I've become wary of `Serializable`, instead favoring plaintext exchange formats like JSON and XML that have broader support. But you're right, in this case it doesn't matter, both require "a little more work," and I am too tired to continue this. Stephen C has given a good answer to the OP's question. Good night, and thanks for the conversation, EJP.

Answer (score 0):

> when I want to de-serialize the existing stored object, it is giving b field value as null;

This behaviour is correct. You've added a field to the parent and removed one from the child. Added fields are deserialized as null from streams that don't contain them, and removed fields are ignored when encountered in streams that contain them.

You need to read the [Versioning of Serializable Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.